# DataContractSerializer not working for MVC DBContext Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm trying to write my object which implements DbContext to a file, however I'm having trouble  getting DataContractSerializer to work. I was looking at this post on the subject http://www.riggshill.com/home/node/24 but I'm getting an error:

`Error  10  'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer' does not contain a definition for 'Serialize' and no extension method 'Serialize' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

My class looks as follows:

```
public class ManagementDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RemoteHost> RemoteHosts {get;set;}
    public DbSet<DataSource> DataSources { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("ManagementData.xml"))
        {
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
            DataContractSerializer srlz = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ManagementDbContext));
            srlz.Serialize(writer, this);
            writer.Close(); // ensure it's properly flushed
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ok so it turns out the sample code I was following was bad and I had mistakes. The line `srlz.Serialize(writer,this)` should have been `srlz.WriteObject(writer,this)`
as shown here [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)
Also I can't serialize an implementation of DbContext and was missing the [Serializable] and [DataContract] attributes on the class, and [DataMember()] on the members as Daniil pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first - you need to use [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute at ManagementDbContext. At second you can not serialize your object because [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is not marked of any attributes.

Basic quide for [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)

Comment: So I simply cannot serialize my object? How can I write it to a file so?

Comment: @judgeja I can only advice make a simple object such as SimpleDbContext with same properties, marked attributes and without inheritance from another object. And copy ManagementDbContext to SimpleDbContext.

Comment: Tried that but it's still having the same problem.. You can see the new class above

Comment: @judgeja All classes such as RemoteHost and DataSource must be marked attributes too.

Comment: When you say be marked attributes too, do you mean have the     [DataContract] and [Serializable] attributes? They do.

Comment: Same error, it's an error compiling by the way. When I look at the DataContractSerializer class, there's no method for Serialize so it seems the error message is for some other reason?

Comment: I'm starting to think the example I was following copied and pasted his code from XML serialisation and didn't make the other relevant changes...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26863/discussion-between-daniil-and-judgeja)